# Check if values contained between two lists - Python

Tags: python

I have to check if each value of the list `f_interp` is contained within a two range:

1. `(1+percentage/100)*omega/60*(diam+eo*N)` and `(1-percentage/100)*omega/60*(diam+eo*N)`
2. `(1+percentage/100)*omega/60*((1+eo)*N-diam)` and `(1-percentage/100)*omega/60*((1+eo)*N-diam)`

where diam goes from 0 to 12 (see `diameters`), eo from 0 to 40 and N is fixed.

Unfortunately I am not that good and my attempt below seems extremely inefficient:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
max_mode = 8
N = 24
percentage = 10
diameters = range(0,int(N/2+1))
...
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for j in range(max_mode):
    for frequency in f_interp[j::max_mode]:
        for eo in np.arange(0,40,1):
            for diam in diameters:
                if frequency <= (1+percentage/100)*omega/60*(diam+eo*N) and frequency >= (1-percentage/100)*omega/60*(diam+eo*N):
                    ax.plot(diam, frequency, '*')
                    ax.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize ='large')
                if frequency <= (1+percentage/100)*omega/60*((1+eo)*N-diam) and frequency >= (1-percentage/100)*omega/60*((1+eo)*N-diam):
                    ax.plot(diam, frequency, '*')
                    ax.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize ='large')
```

Therefore I am here to ask you if there is way to improve efficiency and how to do so.

Comment: Hey, so I quickly calculated the number of iterations you are doing and if I'm not mistaken, it's 16640! That is easily doable with the g.o. python `for` loop. Most likely you are bound by the ´ax.plot´ calls, which take a while in matplotlib. It seems to me that there is not much that can be optimized, unless you completely rework your code (Hint: Count the number of calls to `ax.plot`). Furthermore there are a few minor inefficiencies in your code, but nothing, that'd be noticable in practice. You could try to make a list of frequencies in numpy, then filter with `where` and then `ax.plot`.

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexNe . I have found by trying with where that my procedure was flawed and not the code itself indeed. Now I have managed to fix it so thank you!